# Can't get loop to print out even numbers up to 237

Tags: java, netbeans

```
//Loop through and print out all even numbers from the numbers list in the same order
//they are received. Don't print any numbers that come after 237 in the sequence.
public class excercise4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {
            951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544, 
            615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941, 
            386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345, 
            399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217, 
            815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717, 
            958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470, 
            743, 527};


        for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {


            int el = numbers[i];
            if (el >= 237) break;
            if (el%2==0)           // using the remainder operator %
            System.out.print(el+" ");  // the Expected Output likes it like this!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `break` do? What is the element at index 0 in your array?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to change this line:

```
if (el >= 237) break;
```

for this one

```
if (el >= 237) continue;
```

Because `break` sentence will go out from the **whole** loop. While `continue` will go to the **next** element of your array.

Comment: @KevinGleeson don't forget to accept any of the answers as well so we can know it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having:

```
if (el >= 237) break;
```

Have:

```
if (el >= 237) continue;
```